# Merge duplicate objects in array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have below array of objects,

```
var data = [
    {
        label: "Book1",
        data: "US edition"
    },
    {
        label: "Book1",
        data: "UK edition"
    },
    {
        label: "Book2",
        data: "CAN edition"
    }
];
```

I want to merge the duplicate objects based on attribute 'label' 
so that Final output will look like below,

```
var data = [
    {
        label: "Book1",
        data: ["US edition", "UK edition"] //data attribute is merged
    },
    {
        label: "Book2",
        data: "CAN edition"
    }
];
```

Can someone help me identify the approach?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/171251/how-can-i-merge-properties-of-two-javascript-objects-dynamically

Comment: In my case, `new Set(array1, array2)` works perfect.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I would probably loop through with `filter`, keeping track of a map of objects I'd seen before, along these lines *(edited to reflect your agreeing that yes, it makes sense to make `(entry).data` always an array)*:

```
var seen = {};
data = data.filter(function(entry) {
    var previous;

    // Have we seen this label before?
    if (seen.hasOwnProperty(entry.label)) {
        // Yes, grab it and add this data to it
        previous = seen[entry.label];
        previous.data.push(entry.data);

        // Don't keep this entry, we've merged it into the previous one
        return false;
    }

    // entry.data probably isn't an array; make it one for consistency
    if (!Array.isArray(entry.data)) {
        entry.data = [entry.data];
    }

    // Remember that we've seen it
    seen[entry.label] = entry;

    // Keep this one, we'll merge any others that match into it
    return true;
});
```

In an ES6 environment, I'd use `seen = new Map()` rather than `seen = {}`.

**Note**: `Array.isArray` was defined by ES5, so some quite older browsers like IE8 won't have it. It can easily be shimmed/polyfilled, though:

```
if (!Array.isArray) {
    Array.isArray = (function() {
        var toString = Object.prototype.toString;
        return function(a) {
            return toString.call(a) === "[object Array]";
        };
    })();
}
```

<s>Side note: I'd probably also **always** make `entry.data` an array, even if I didn't see two values for it, because consistent data structures are easier to deal with. I didn't do that above because your end result showed `data` being just a string when there was only one matching entry.</s> *(We've done that above now.)*

**Live example** (ES5 version):

```js
var data = [
    {
        label: "Book1",
        data: "US edition"
    },
    {
        label: "Book1",
        data: "UK edition"
    },
    {
        label: "Book2",
        data: "CAN edition"
    }
];
snippet.log("Before:");
snippet.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, 2), "pre");
var seen = {};
data = data.filter(function(entry) {
    var previous;

    // Have we seen this label before?
    if (seen.hasOwnProperty(entry.label)) {
        // Yes, grab it and add this data to it
        previous = seen[entry.label];
        previous.data.push(entry.data);

        // Don't keep this entry, we've merged it into the previous one
        return false;
    }

    // entry.data probably isn't an array; make it one for consistency
    if (!Array.isArray(entry.data)) {
        entry.data = [entry.data];
    }

    // Remember that we've seen it
    seen[entry.label] = entry;

    // Keep this one, we'll merge any others that match into it
    return true;
});
snippet.log("After:");
snippet.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, 2), "pre");
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

Comment: What an optimized and superb logic :)

Comment: How does data get the updated array for the duplicated ones?

Comment: @FinbarMaginn: I don't understand the question.

Comment: I don't see how the merged array is assigned to the returned array item with the same label. Also I was wondering if this whole thing could be rewritten with a Map and Reduce?

Comment: @FinbarMaginn: `entry.data = [entry.data];` and `previous = seen[entry.label]; previous.data.push(entry.data);` are what do that. Re map/reduce: Possibly. There's no need for the complexity over the simple loop above, though.

Comment: I see how `previous.data.push(entry.data)` adds to the array for that label and is stored in previous, but I don't see how this is previous var is assigned to anything outside, ie in the item in the data var.

Comment: @FinbarMaginn: I suggest studying the code closely, stepping through it with a debugger, etc. Basically: We update `entry.data` with the array, and we remember that reference in `seen`, keyed by the label. Later, we look it up in `seen`, keyed by the label.

Comment: When the first item is an array, it outputs each item inside it as a seperate array, is there a way around this?

Comment: this seems to mutate the original array. Is there a way to avoid that?

Comment: @peterflanagan - It doesn't mutate the original array, but it does mutate the objects in the original array. To avoid that, you'd need `map`, something like this (ES2015+): https://pastebin.com/LQPzAxew

Answer (score 8):

Try with below approach, it works find and it is short

```
 var data = [
    {
        label: "Book1",
        data: "US edition"
    },
    {
        label: "Book1",
        data: "UK edition"
    },
    {
        label: "Book2",
        data: "CAN edition"
    }
];

const result = Array.from(new Set(data.map(s => s.label)))
    .map(lab => {
      return {
        label: lab,
        data: data.filter(s => s.label === lab).map(edition => edition.data)
      }
    })

console.log(result);
```

Comment: This works great but a little note, if you have more keys for the object you will need to find a way to add them, my solution for this `...data.filter(f => f.label === lab)[0],`

Answer (score 3):

I came across the same situation and I was hoping to use the `Set` instead of mine here

```js
const data = [
  {
    label: "Book1",
    data: "US edition"
  },
  {
    label: "Book1",
    data: "UK edition"
  },
  {
    label: "Book2",
    data: "CAN edition"
  },
  {
    label: "Book3",
    data: "CAN edition"
  },
  {
    label: "Book3",
    data: "CANII edition"
  }
];

const filteredArr = data.reduce((acc, current) => {
  const x = acc.find(item => item.label === current.label);
  if (!x) {
    const newCurr = {
      label: current.label,
      data: [current.data]
    }
    return acc.concat([newCurr]);
  } else {
    const currData = x.data.filter(d => d === current.data);
    if (!currData.length) {
      const newData = x.data.push(current.data);
      const newCurr = {
        label: current.label,
        data: newData
      }
      return acc;
    } else {
      return acc;
    }
    
  }
}, []);

console.log(filteredArr);
```

Answer (score 1):

This code is tested on latest version of firefox. To work on other browsers change Array.isArray for a library as lodash or whatever you prefer.

```
var data = [
    {
        label: "Book1",
        data: "US edition"
    },
    {
        label: "Book1",
        data: "UK edition"
    },
    {
        label: "Book2",
        data: "CAN edition"
    }
],
i = 0,
j = data.length - 1,
current;

for (;i < data.length; i++) {
  current = data[i];
  for (;j > i; j--) {
     if (current.label === data[j].label) {
       if (Array.isArray(current.data)) {
         current.data = current.data.concat([data[j].data]);
       } else {
         current.data = [].concat([data[j].data, current.data]);
       }
       data.splice(j, 1);
     }

  }
} 

console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var data = [
    {
        label: "Book1",
        data: "US edition"
    },
    {
        label: "Book1",
        data: "UK edition"
    },
    {
        label: "Book2",
        data: "CAN edition"
    }
].filter(function(e, index ,b) {
    k = b.map(z => z.label)
    if(k.includes(e.label, index+1)){
        indexPosition = k.indexOf(e.label, index+1);
        b[indexPosition].data = (e.data+"||"+b[indexPosition].data);
        
    }else{
        e.data = e.data.split("||").length > 1 ? e.data.split("||") : e.data;
        return e;
    }
});

console.log(data)
```