# Is there a shorter way to merge duplicated objects

Tags: javascript, node.js

I was curious if there was a shorter way to accomplish this?

Check if there are duplicates by matching certain properties then push the duplicated array.items into the original array.items

```
var array = [
    {type: "Fruit", something: "abc", more: "properties", items: [{word:"Apple", abc: "ok"}]},
    {type: "Fruit", something: "abc", more: "properties", items: [{word:"Orange", abc: "ok"}]}
];
```

merge(array) would become

```
array = [
    {type: "Fruit", something: "abc", more: "properties", items:[{word:"Apple", abc: "ok"}, {word:"Orange", abc: "ok"}]}
];

     merge: function(arr) {
        var rec, dupeIndices, foundDupes;
        for (var idx = 0, len = arr.length; idx < len - 1; ++idx) {
            rec = arr[idx];
            if (rec === null) continue;
            dupeIndices = findDupeIndices(rec, arr.slice(idx + 1), idx + 1);
            if (dupeIndices.length === 0) continue;
            foundDupes = true;
            processDupes(rec, dupeIndices, arr);
        }
        if (foundDupes) cleanUp(arr);
    },
    cleanUp: function(arr) {
        for (var idx = 0; idx < arr.length; ++idx) {
            if (arr[idx] === null) arr.splice(idx--, 1);
        }
    },
    processDupes: function(rec, dupeIndices, arr) {
        var dupeRealIdx, dupeRec;
        for (var dupeIdx = 0, dupesLen = dupeIndices.length; dupeIdx < dupesLen; ++dupeIdx) {
            dupeRealIdx = dupeIndices[dupeIdx];
            dupeRec = arr[dupeRealIdx];
            updateRecord(rec, dupeRec);
            arr[dupeRealIdx] = null;
        }
    },
    findDupeIndices: function(rec, arr, offset) {
        var other, result = [];
        for (var idx = 0, len = arr.length; idx < len; ++idx) {
            other = arr[idx];
            if (other === null) continue;
            if (isDupe(rec, other)) result.push(idx + offset);
        }
        return result;
    },
    isDupe: function(a, b) {
        return (a.type === b.type && a.something === b.something);
    },
    updateRecord: function(rec, dupe) {
        for (var i = 0; i < dupe.items.length; i++) {
            rec.items.push(dupe.items[i]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30025965/merge-duplicate-objects-in-array-of-objects

Comment: What is expected result for array?

Comment: I edited because your data structures were not formatted as code and thus not very readable.  If you want to edit some more to clear things up further, you can do that yourself with the 'edit' link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an object to help sort, here im sorting on the type and combining the items

```
 var obj = [
    {type: "Fruit", something: "abc", more: "properties", items: [{word:"Apple", abc: "ok"}]},
    {type: "Fruit", something: "abc", more: "properties", items: [{word:"Orange", abc: "ok"}]}
];

var sorted = {};
obj.forEach(function(element){
  if(sorted[element.type]){
    sorted[element.type].items.push.apply(sorted[element.type].items,element.items)
  }else{
    sorted[element.type] = {
      type: element.type,
      something: element.something,
      more: element.more,
      items:element.items
    }
  }

});

var sortedarray = Object.keys(sorted).map(function(item){
return sorted[item]});

console.log(sortedarray);
```

working example : http://codepen.io/nilestanner/pen/NAkZbz

Comment: Could you explain why I'd use push.apply instead of .push

Comment: I used push.apply because I was merging two arrays. In your example object Items was an array, so this way all items of the object are added

Answer (score 1):

Do you need to remove duplicates?

```
var arr = [
    {type: "Fruit", items:[{word:"Apple"}]}, 
    {type: "Fruit", items:[{word:"Orange"}]}
];

var obj = arr.reduce(function(obj, i) {
    obj[i.type] = [].concat(obj[i.type] || [], i.items); return obj;    
}, {});

var res = [];
for (var key in obj)
    res.push({type: key, items: obj[key]});
    // or to unique items
    // res.push({type: key, items: obj[key].filter(function (e, i, r) { return r.indexOf(e) == i})}); 

console.log(res);
```

Comment: Yes I would need to remove duplicates also I would need to match with multiple properties.