# How to reconstruct array of objects based on duplicate keys?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, object, javascript-objects

I'm getting an array object that looks like this. My goal is to combine or merge them based on duplicate keys.

```
documents: [
    {
        image: 'sample image 1',
        id_side: 'Front',
        type: 'Passport'
    },
    {
        image: 'sample image 2',
        id_side: 'Back',
        type: 'Passport'
    },
    {
        image: 'sample image 3',
        id_side: 'Back',
        type: 'License'
    }
]
```

How can I arrange it to look like this?

```
documents: [
    {
        documentType: 'Passport',
        requiredDocs: [
            {
                image: 'sample image 1',
                id_side: 'Front',
                type: 'Passport'
            },
            {
                image: 'sample image 2',
                id_side: 'Back',
                type: 'Passport'
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        documentType: 'License',
        requiredDocs: [
            {
                image: 'sample image 3',
                id_side: 'Back',
                type: 'License'
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I have found a similar question but I can't seem to make it work in my case.
See the similar question in this link:
[How to merge/combine array of objects based on duplicate keys?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41124832/how-to-merge-combine-array-of-objects-based-on-duplicate-keys)

Comment: If you ok with using libraries - lodash [groupBy](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#groupBy) is what you need

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve your output with this

```
const documents = [
  {
    image: "sample image 1",
    id_side: "Front",
    type: "Passport"
  },
  {
    image: "sample image 2",
    id_side: "Back",
    type: "Passport"
  },
  {
    image: "sample image 3",
    id_side: "Back",
    type: "License"
  }
];

let output = {};
  documents.forEach((docs) => {
    if (output[docs.type]) {
      output[docs.type].requiredDocs.push(docs);
    } else {
      output[docs.type] = {
        documentType: docs.type,
        requiredDocs: [docs]
      };
    }
  });

  console.log(Object.values(output));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to create an accumulation object, and then [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) the [entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) of that object to your desired output format:

```js
const data = [{
  image: 'sample image 1',
  id_side: 'Front',
  type: 'Passport'
}, {
  image: 'sample image 2',
  id_side: 'Back',
  type: 'Passport'
}, {
  image: 'sample image 3',
  id_side: 'Back',
  type: 'License'
}];

const result = Object.entries(data.reduce((a, v) => ({
  ...a,
  [v.type]: [...a[v.type] || [], v]
}), {})).map(([documentType, requiredDocs]) => ({
  documentType,
  requiredDocs
}));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

This assumes that the key that you want to deal with is `type`. Build an object mapping from the type to all the relevant objects, and then `map` it to the desired format.

```js
const obj={documents:[{image:'sample image 1',id_side:'Front',type:'Passport'},{image:'sample image 2',id_side:'Back',type:'Passport'},{image:'sample image 3',id_side:'Back',type:'License'}]};

let types = obj.documents.reduce((a, { type, ...r }) => {
  a[type] = a[type] || [];
  a[type].push({ type, ...r });
  return a;
}, {});

let result = Object.entries(types).map(([ documentType, requiredDocs ]) => ({ documentType, requiredDocs }));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: auto; }
```

Answer (score 0):

First you can use an Object {} to store as key value pair such that unique items will be treated as key:

```
const data = [{
  image: 'sample image 1',
  id_side: 'Front',
  type: 'Passport'
}, {
  image: 'sample image 2',
  id_side: 'Back',
  type: 'Passport'
}, {
  image: 'sample image 3',
  id_side: 'Back',
  type: 'License'
}];
const Obj = {}, arr = []
data.forEach(element => {
  if (Obj[element.type]) Obj[element.type].push(element)
  else Obj[element.type] = [element]
})
for (const eachType in Obj) {
  arr.push({ documentType: eachType, requiredDocs: Obj[eachType] })
}
console.log(arr)
```