# Merge duplicate multidimensional objects in array of objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, merge

I am looking to find a way to combine objects in arrays based on id values. I can make it work using the [filter method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30025965/merge-duplicate-objects-in-array-of-objects) for the top level, but not sure how to make sure that all subGroups and such are merged properly. Here is an example:

```
[
    {
        id: 1,
        name: "A"
        subGroup: [
            {
                id: 1,
                name: "AA"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: "B"
        subGroup: [
            {
                id: 4,
                name: "DD"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        id: 1,
        name: "A"
        subGroup: [
            {
                id: 2,
                name: "BB"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        name: "C"
        subGroup: [
            {
                id: 5,
                name: "EE"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: "B"
        subGroup: [
            {
                id: 4,
                other: "Something else"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        id: 1,
        name: "A"
        subGroup2: [
            {
                id: 7,
                name: "GG"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        id: 1,
        name: "A"
        subGroup: [
            {
                id: 1,
                name: "AA",
                subSubGroup: [
                    id: 10,
                    name: "II",
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I am looking to take something like that and merge it like:

```
[
    {
        id: 1,
        name: "A"
        subGroup: [
            {
                id: 1,
                name: "AA",
                subSubGroup: [
                    id: 10,
                    name: "II",
                ]
            },
            {
                id: 2,
                name: "BB"
            }
        ],
        subGroup2: [
            {
                id: 7,
                name: "GG"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: "B"
        subGroup: [
            {
                id: 4,
                name: "DD",
                other: "Something else"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        name: "C"
        subGroup: [
            {
                id: 5,
                name: "EE"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What are your initial data structures ?

Comment: The first code snippet is the initial data and the second is how I am looking to have it setup.

Comment: What is the relationship between data ?

Comment: I am looking to combine by the id attribute in each array. The subgroups are sections inside the groups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a recursive approach for properties which are arrays and group on `id` and `name` property.

```js
var data = [{ id: 1, name: "A", subGroup: [{ id: 1, name: "AA" }] }, { id: 2, name: "B", subGroup: [{ id: 4, name: "DD" }] }, { id: 1, name: "A", subGroup: [{ id: 2, name: "BB" }] }, { id: 3, name: "C", subGroup: [{ id: 5, name: "EE" }] }, { id: 2, name: "B", subGroup: [{ id: 4, other: "Something else" }] }, { id: 1, name: "A", subGroup2: [{ id: 7, name: "GG" }] }, { id: 1, name: "A", subGroup: [{ id: 1, name: "AA", subSubGroup: [{ id: 10, name: "II" }] }] }],
    result = [];

data.forEach(function iter(r) {
    return function (o) {
        var ref = r.find(p => o.id === p.id && o.name === p.name);
        if (!ref) {
            r.push(o);
            return;
        }
        Object
            .keys(o)
            .filter(k => Array.isArray(o[k]))
            .forEach(k => o[k].forEach(iter(ref[k] = ref[k] || [])));
    };
}(result));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thanks Nina. Just an FYI to anyone viewing is that this is ES6 code, but works great!