# Merge duplicate array of object key to single array

Tags: javascript, angular, angular6

[image]

this is the desire output i am looking for

```
[
    productId:106290,
    productserialno:[{
    "12121",
    "212121"
}]
]
```

Comment: Simple JS function can do this for you. What's the problem?

Comment: unaware of angular 6 way can you share the sample ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Merge duplicate objects in array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30025965/merge-duplicate-objects-in-array-of-objects)

Comment: Man my a** friend used this account to ask this question and it was resolved by Sajeetharan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
var myArray = [
    {productId: 116605, productserialno: "324234"},
    {productId: 106290, productserialno: "12121"},
    {productId: 106290, productserialno: "12121"},
    {productId: 106293, productserialno: "4324343"}
];

var grouped = myArray.reduce(function (obj, product) {
    obj[product.productId] = obj[product.productId] || [];
    obj[product.productId].push(product.productserialno);
    return obj;
}, {});

var groups = Object.keys(grouped).map(function (key) {
    return {product: key, productserialno: grouped[key]};
});

var pre = document.createElement("pre");
pre.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(groups, null, 4);
document.body.appendChild(pre);
```