# Merge Duplicate object in array

Tags: javascript

I have an array  I need to merge duplicate values with the sum of amount.
What would be an efficient algorithm

```
var arr = [{
    item: {
        id: 1,
        name: "Abc"
    },
    amount: 1
}, {
    item: {
        id: 1,
        name: "Abc"
    },
    amount: 2
}, {
    item: {
        id: 2,
        name: "Abc"
    },
    amount: 2
},{
    item: {
        id: 1,
        name: "Abc"
    },
    amount: 2
}]
```

I need solution as

```
[{
    item: {
        id: 1,
        name: "Abc"
    },
    amount: 5
}, {
    item: {
        id: 2,
        name: "Abc"
    },
] amount: 2
}]
```

Comment: please add, what you have tried.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Merge duplicate objects in array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30025965/merge-duplicate-objects-in-array-of-objects)

Answer (score 4):

simply  use `Object.values()` with  `Array.reudce()` to merge objects and then get the values:

```js
var arr = [{ item: { id: 1, name: "Abc" }, amount: 1 }, { item: { id: 1, name: "Abc" }, amount: 2 }, { item: { id: 2, name: "Abc" }, amount: 2 },{ item: { id: 1, name: "Abc" }, amount: 2 }];

var result = Object.values(arr.reduce((a,curr)=>{

  if(!a[curr.item.id])
    a[curr.item.id] = Object.assign({},curr); // Object.assign() is used so that the original element(object) is not mutated.
   else 
     a[curr.item.id].amount += curr.amount;
    return a;
},{}));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

used `map` to catch em all :D

```js
var arr = [{ item: { id: 1, name: "Abc" }, amount: 1 }, { item: { id: 1, name: "Abc" }, amount: 2 }, { item: { id: 2, name: "Abc" }, amount: 2 },{ item: { id: 1, name: "Abc" }, amount: 2 }];

var res = {};
arr.map((e) => {
  if(!res[e.item.id]) res[e.item.id] = Object.assign({},e); // clone, credits to: @amrender singh
  else res[e.item.id].amount += e.amount;
});
console.log(Object.values(res));
```