# merge duplicate objects in an array and add additional property

Tags: javascript, node.js

i have a problem, with my code basically i'm trying to merge the duplicate objects and add the additional property 'admin' set to 'true' and for unique objects additional property 'admin' set to 'false'

```
const addresses = [{name: 'Paul', id: 2}, {name: 'John', id: 1}, {name: 'John', id: 1}];

//combine duplicate object and add property admin: true

let result = [];
addresses.forEach(elem => {
  let match = result.find(r => r.id === elem.id);
  if(match) {
    return {...match, ...elem, admin: true};
  } else {
    result.push({...elem, admin: false });
  }
});
```

but im doing this incorrectly as the output i get is

```
const addresses = [{name: 'Paul', id: 2}, {name: 'John', id: 1}, {name: 'John', id: 1}];
```

Comment: You are modifying `result` not the original array. Note that `return` in `forEach` does nothing

Comment: ahh that makes sense!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Merge duplicate objects in array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30025965/merge-duplicate-objects-in-array-of-objects)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `reduce` to create a unique array that sets `admin` property to `true` for duplicate addresses as follows:

```js
const addresses = [{name: 'Paul', id: 2}, {name: 'John', id: 1}, {name: 'John', id: 1}];

const result = addresses.reduce((acc, address) => {
  const dup = acc.find(addr => addr.id === address.id);
  if (dup) {
    dup.admin = true;
    return acc;
  }
  address.admin = false;
  return acc.concat(address);
}, [])

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

Using [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

```js
const addresses = [{name: 'Paul', id: 2}, {name: 'John', id: 1}, {name: 'John', id: 1}];

const result = addresses.reduce((a, o) => ({...a, ...{
  [o.id]: { ...o, admin: !a[o.id] }
}}), {});

console.log(Object.values(result));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array#reduce` to group the unique addresses and then check for `admin` property in the object and accordingly assign the value.

```js
const addresses = [{name: 'Paul', id: 2}, {name: 'John', id: 1}, {name: 'John', id: 1}],
      users = Object.values(addresses.reduce((r,o) => {
        r[o.id] = {...o, admin: !r[o.id]};
        return r;
      }, {}));
console.log(users);
```