# merge duplicate objects in an array and combine sub array of each object

Tags: javascript, array-merge

I am trying to merge objects based off of Id, and merge each array that lives inside each `account` (object), but instead of merging the contents of accountList, the code overwrites the array, if there is a matching id.

I've made a new array and used the .find method to find matching objects based off there id, but stuck on how to merge the `accountList` together

```
const accounts = [
    {
    "Id": 103,
    "accountList": [
      {}
    ]
  },
  {
    "Id": 103,
    "accountList": [
      {
        "tokenId": "5aasdasdsdnjn3434nadd",
        "featureId": 2840
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "Id": 112,
    "accountList": [
      {
        "tokenId": "5d30775bef4a722c38aefaaa",
        "featureId": 2877
      }
    ]
  },
    {
    "Id": 112,
    "accountList": [
      {
        "tokenId": "5d30775bef4a722c38aefccc",
        "featureId": 2856
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

```
let result = [];
accounts.forEach(account => {
  let match = result.find(r => r.Id === account.Id);
  // console.log(match)
  if(match) {
   Object.assign(match, account);
    //tried using spread operator instead of object assign, but didnt work
    //  match = {...match, ...account}
  } else {
    result.push(account);
  }
});
```

`console.log( JSON.stringify(result, null, 2))`

The result which i need is to merge the object based off their id, and merge the contents of the `accountList` together, like so:

```
[
  {
    "Id": 103,
    "accountList": [
      {
        "tokenId": "5aasdasdsdnjn3434nadd",
        "featureId": 2840
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "Id": 112,
    "accountList": [
      {
        "tokenId": "5d30775bef4a722c38aefaaa",
        "featureId": 2877
      },
      {
        "tokenId": "5d30775bef4a722c38aefccc",
        "featureId": 2856
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: ahh sorry i clicked the wrong one

Comment: No worries, I was glad to help.

Comment: I updated my code, initially the empty object was also included. This has been fixed now. My bad.

Comment: Thank you to everyone who helped :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Merge duplicate objects in array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30025965/merge-duplicate-objects-in-array-of-objects)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, `reduce()` would do the job:

```js
const accounts = [{"Id":103,"accountList":[{}]},{"Id":103,"accountList":[{"tokenId":"5aasdasdsdnjn3434nadd","featureId":2840}]},{"Id":112,"accountList":[{"tokenId":"5d30775bef4a722c38aefaaa","featureId":2877}]},{"Id":112,"accountList":[{"tokenId":"5d30775bef4a722c38aefccc","featureId":2856}]}];

const result = [...accounts
        .reduce((r, o) => {
          const record = r.get(o.Id)||{}
          r.set(o.Id, {
            Id: o.Id,
            accountList: [
              ...(record.accountList||[]),
              ...o.accountList.filter(o => 
                Object.keys(o).length != 0)
            ]            
          })
          return r
        }, new Map())
        .values()]

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {min-height: 100%}
```

Comment: but if accountlist:{} it also pushed

Comment: @RakibulIslam : That doesn't seem to be the case according to OP's example.

Answer (score 1):

Using `Array.prototype.reduce` we can accumulate the results in the final `result` array.

In the reduce call back just find the matching object using Id and merge the `accountList` array and not the object as you were doing in your code.

```js
const accounts=[{"Id":103,"accountList":[{}]},{"Id":103,"accountList":[{"tokenId":"5aasdasdsdnjn3434nadd","featureId":2840}]},{"Id":112,"accountList":[{"tokenId":"5d30775bef4a722c38aefaaa","featureId":2877}]},{"Id":112,"accountList":[{"tokenId":"5d30775bef4a722c38aefccc","featureId":2856}]}];

const result = accounts.reduce((acc, account) => {
     let match = acc.find(r => r.Id === account.Id);
     if(match) {
       match.accountList.push(...account.accountList); //push previous array
     } else {
       const act = { ...account }; 
       act.accountList = account.accountList.filter((obj) => Object.keys(obj).length);
       acc.push(act);
     }
     return acc;
}, []);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use [Array.concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat):

```
    let result = [];
    accounts.forEach(account => {
      let match = result.find(r => r.Id === account.Id);
      // console.log(match)
      if(match) {
        match.accountList = match.accountList.concat(account.accountList);
      } else {
        result.push(account);
      }
    });

for (let res of result) {
  console.log('res.Id: ', res.Id, res.accountList)
}

// res.Id:  103 [ {}, { tokenId: '5aasdasdsdnjn3434nadd', featureId: 2840 } ]
// res.Id:  112 [ { tokenId: '5d30775bef4a722c38aefaaa', featureId: 2877 },
//   { tokenId: '5d30775bef4a722c38aefccc', featureId: 2856 } ]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use `match.accountList.push(...account.accountList);` instead of the object assign, spread operator can be used to push the element into the result item(`match`):

```js
let accounts = [{ "Id": 103, "accountList": [{}] }, { "Id": 103, "accountList": [{ "tokenId": "5aasdasdsdnjn3434nadd", "featureId": 2840 }] }, { "Id": 112, "accountList": [{ "tokenId": "5d30775bef4a722c38aefaaa", "featureId": 2877 }] }, { "Id": 112, "accountList": [{ "tokenId": "5d30775bef4a722c38aefccc", "featureId": 2856 }] }];
let result = [];
accounts.forEach(account => {
  (match = result.find(r => r.Id === account.Id), match ? match.accountList.push(...account.accountList) : result.push(account))
});
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const isNotEmptyObject = objc => Object.entries(objc).length > 0;

function mergeAccounts(accounts) {
    const uniqueAccounts = new Map();
    accounts.forEach(account => {
        if(uniqueAccounts.has(account.Id)) {
            let uniqueAccount = uniqueAccounts.get(account.Id);
            if(account.accountList && account.accountList.length > 0)
                uniqueAccount.accountList.push(...account.accountList);
                uniqueAccount.accountList = uniqueAccount.accountList.filter(isNotEmptyObject);
        } else {
            uniqueAccounts.set(account.Id, account);
        }
    });
  return Array.from(uniqueAccounts.values());
}
```

This will merge all the accounts having same ids. Hope this helps :)